# Como puedo transformar un codigo svg en una imagen con php?

Tags: php, svg

estoy realizando un proyecto donde creo un carnet con la liberia [Fabric](http://fabricjs.com/), de alli lo exporto en forma de SVG y me da el siguiente codigo:

```
'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="318" height="500" viewBox="0 0 318 500" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 5.3.0</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"  >
</g>
<g transform="matrix(3.76 0 0 3.76 204.3 159.33)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-27.22" y="6.28" >accion</tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(-0.15 0.7 -0.7 -0.01 22.82 126.51)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-65.54" y="12.57" >Nombre</tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(0.71 0 0 0.71 154.37 271.38)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-52.19" y="12.57" >cedula</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>'
```

Lo que quisiera es tranformar este codigo SVG en una imagen para guardarla en un directorio, cosa que no he logrado. Probe con codigo nativo de nativo de php

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$codigo_svg = 'MI_SVG';

// Crear la imagen vacía
$imagen = imagecreatetruecolor(1280, 720);

// Cargar la imagen desde el SVG
$imagen_fondo = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/15/13/51/polynesia-3021072_1280.jpg');

// Dibujar la imagen de fondo
imagecopy($imagen, $imagen_fondo, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1280, 720);

// Dibujar los textos
$color_texto = imagecolorallocate($imagen, 0, 0, 0);

// Crear un objeto SimpleXML a partir del código SVG
$xml = simplexml_load_string($codigo_svg);

foreach ($xml as $obj) {

    // Validamos que exista texto
    if (isset($obj->text)) {

        // [4] = x ; [5] = y
        $coordinates = explode(" ", $obj["transform"]);


        $x = (float) $coordinates[4];
        $y = (float) $coordinates[5];
        // $x = (float) $obj->text->tspan["x"];
        // $y = (float) $obj->text->tspan["y"];
        $contenido = (string) $obj->text->tspan;


        // // Cargar la fuente
        $fuente = 'Roboto.ttf';

        // // Dibujar el texto
        imagettftext($imagen, 40, 0, $x, $y, $color_texto, $fuente, $contenido);

    }
}

// Guardar la imagen en un archivo PNG
imagepng($imagen, 'MI NOMBRE DE ARCHIVO');
```

pero no lo genera completamente, puede recrearlo pero no con las mismas caracteristicas de por ejemplo, la rotacion de un texto.

Estoy probando con la liberia [PHP-SVG](https://github.com/meyfa/php-svg), pero esta nisiquiera logrA mostrar nada, este fue el codigo que use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use SVG\SVG;

$svg = 'MI_SVG';


header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng( $image->toRasterImage(318, 500) );
```

Y ya no se que mas puedo intentar...
Escucho sus sugerencias, saludos!

Comment: lee un poco por aca:  https://metacpan.org/pod/Image%3A%3AMagick

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer esto del lado del servidor? Si vas a usar la imagen para incluirla en la página, puedes incluir directamente el código SVG y que sea el navegador el que se encargue de dibujarlo.

Comment: La cosa es que necesito la imagen en archivo, para que esa imagen generada a partir del svg la descargue una app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes hacerlo creando el archivo `SVG` e ingresando el contenido del mismo.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

// Codigo del SVG
$codigo_svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="318" height="500" viewBox="0 0 318 500" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 5.3.0</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"></g>
<g transform="matrix(3.76 0 0 3.76 204.3 159.33)" style="">
    <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-27.22" y="6.28" >accion</tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(-0.15 0.7 -0.7 -0.01 22.82 126.51)" style="" >
    <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-65.54" y="12.57" >Nombre</tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(0.71 0 0 0.71 154.37 271.38)" style="">
    <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-52.19" y="12.57" >cedula</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>';

// Nombre del archivo
$file_svg = 'mi_svg.svg';

// Agregamos el encabezado
$codigo_svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . $codigo_svg;

// Creamos el archivo
file_put_contents($file_svg, $codigo_svg);
```

---

Mas ínfo:

- [SVG > Document Structure](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html)
- [PHP > file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer que el navegador se encargue de dibujar la imagen representada por el SVG.

Te dejo este ejemplo de cómo colocarlo con javascript del lado del cliente, pero sería más o menos equivalente incluirlo directamente desde el servidor en un elemento `<img>`.

```js
const svgCarnet = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="318" height="500" viewBox="0 0 318 500" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 5.3.0</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"  >
</g>
<g transform="matrix(3.76 0 0 3.76 204.3 159.33)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="20" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-27.22" y="6.28" >accion</tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(-0.15 0.7 -0.7 -0.01 22.82 126.51)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-65.54" y="12.57" >Nombre</tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(0.71 0 0 0.71 154.37 271.38)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-52.19" y="12.57" >cedula</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>
`

//document.documentElement.innerHTML = svgCarnet;

const contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor");

var mysvg = new Image();
mysvg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + escape(svgCarnet);
    
contenedor.appendChild(mysvg);
```

```html
<div id="contenedor"></div>
```

Comment: La "desventaja" de hacerlo así es la imposibilidad de que el navegador ponga en cache el archivo. La ventaja... que el navegador no ponga en cache el archivo  xD

Comment: Seria util pero la cosa es que necesito la imagen en archivo, para que esa imagen generada a partir del svg la descargue una app